# Delphi -> Delphi prism, how to use array of records?

Tags: arrays, delphi, record, delphi-prism, oxygene

I'm learning Delphi Prism, and i don't find how to write the following code with it :

```
type
  TRapportItem = record
   Label : String;
   Value : Int16;
   AnomalieComment : String;
  end;

type 
  TRapportCategorie = record
    Label : String;
    CategoriesItems : Array of TRapportItem;
  end;

type 
  TRapportContent = record
    Categories : array of TRapportCategorie;
  end;
```

Then, somewhere, i try to put items in the array :

```
rapport.Categories[i].Label:=l.Item(i).InnerText;
```

But it doesn't work.. Can someone enlight me?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the code where you declare and initialize the variable 'rapport'?

Comment: I only added 'rapport : TRapportContent;' to the protected part of the interface. Did i miss something? I also tried to declare CategoriesItems as  Array [0..64] of TRapportItem; but i had the same issue.

Thanks for replying so fast!

Comment: i found another test i made yesterday: using 'regular' delphi i can write setlength(rapport.Categories,10); when declaring my array as dynamic, but i can't found how to write the same using prism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You didn't specify exactly what "didn't work". You should include the error in questions like this.
- Arrays are reference types, and they start out with the value `nil`. They need to be initialized before elements can be accessed.

You can do this with the `new` operator:

```
rapport.Categories = new TRapportCategorie[10]; // 0..9
```

- Arrays are quite a low-level type. Usually it's better to work with `List<T>` instead.

So you'd declare:

```
Categories: List<TRapportCategorie>;
```

- But lists also need initializing, using the `new` operator. Also, modifying the return value of the indexer on a list containing a value type will be modifying a copy, not the original, which leads to the next point.
- Records are usually not the best data type for representing data, as they are not reference types; it's very easy to end up modifying a copy of the data, rather than the original data. It's usually best to use classes instead, where you can put all the initialization code (such as allocating the array or list) in the constructor.

Comment: Thank you! I switched to the use of a list and it now works!

rapport.Categories:= new List<TRapportCategorie>;

Using some kind of classe was planned, because this code will have to be used by two different apps, but i wanted some kind of quick prototyping here.

Thanks!

Comment: +1 on using a List<T> or Dictionary<T> with the key as the category name instead.